# react context is giving undefined object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

In my react application I am trying to use context api. In my component I am importing the context but it is giving error that object can not destructure the property. I am trying to implement cart functionality in my app. I am using hooks.

## ImgContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const ImgContext = createContext();

const ImgConProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [myCart, setMyCart] = useState([]);

    return(
    <ImgContext.Provider value={{myCart, setMyCart}}>
        {children}
    </ImgContext.Provider>
    )
}

export {ImgContext, ImgConProvider}
```

## ImageGrid.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import ImageGrid from './ImageGrid';
import { ImgContext } from './Context/ImageContext';

const Home = () => {

    const { myCart } = useContext(ImgContext);

    return (
    <div className="App">
      {myCart}
    </div>
    )
}

export default  Home;
```

Comment: Is the home component a child of the context provider ?

Comment: yes the home is a child to the context provider

Comment: Try giving an empty object to the createContext, like createContext({}) ?

Comment: Yes, It worked. Add this as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, Added and answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing a a default value when creating the context. If there is a scenario where the component doenst have access to a provider the value from context would be undefined which maybe causing the issue.
Better provide a default value.

```
const ImgContext = createContext({});
```

Comment: It is not giving any error but can not access the setMyCart function. Any idea why?

Comment: probably the its not having access to the provider, check that again n see

Comment: Fixed it, It was a typo.